# Functions without Laplace transform?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, laplace-transform

We have just started working with Laplace transformations at our university course. One of the I came across as following:

Provide three examples of functions for which the Laplace transform does not exist.

We use the book written by Kreyszig "Advanced Engineering Mathematics".

I would have answered where $S > 0$ and $S > K$, I am not sure what the third kind of function would be. In addition I am unsure if this is even the answer they are looking for, I am hoping someone more experienced could provide me with some suggestions. Worst case scenario I get my answer in two weeks time when I hand in the assignment :)

Comment: Laplace transform for $f(t)$ works if $\int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t) dt$ converges. So if your function grows so fast that no decaying exponential can stop it then the integral diverges. Think about fast growing functions, even faster than any $e^{at}$ to find an example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The function $e^{e^t}$ could be an answer?
Aside: Bilateral Laplace transform of $e^{-e^{-t}}$ is Gamma function?

Answer (score 1):

Find something that grows too fast for the exponentially-decaying damping factor $e^{-st}$ (where $t$ is the variable of integration) in the defining integral of the transform to cancel. What do you know of that grows more quickly than an exponential function?

Answer (score 1):

Find some functions that exist $\lim\limits_{t\to a}f(t)$ diverges for some positive real numbers $a$ , e.g. $\tan t$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$F(t)=\frac{1}{t}$$
Laplace transformation of this function does not exists